# Difference between vacuum and pseudovacuum vector?

Tags: mathematical-physics, vectors, vacuum

What exactly is the difference between the vacuum and pseudovacuum vector?

In my case the ground state of a system is the vacuum vector and by letting operators act on that vacuum vector magnons are generated.

Since i've read quite often about a pseudovacuum vector (in other sources, for other systems) i'd like to know, what's the difference?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but "*we have introduced elements, called "vacuums" to consider the state vectors and the configuration spaces within the world of extended algebra of calculus with various expressions. We have found several strange elements, called polar elements, and an extended notions of vacuums, which were called pseudo-vacuums in our paper. These are not established notions in mathematical physics, but we are thinking that these must propose new frontier for mathematical physics*" http://arxiv.org/abs/1210.3426

Comment: Can you list some of those sources?